# update query doesn't work in ZF 1

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

my sql-query doesn't work. here is my query.

```
   public function deletes($poss) {
       $where = array('pos > ?' => $poss);
       $this->update(['pos' => 'pos - 1'], $where);
}
```

it's seems he does every pos -1 instead of the ones greater than $poss.

please help.

Comment: This code works as it should. It sets word `pos-1` in `pos` column for all fields where `pos` column was greater than `$poss`. Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **Zend_Db_Expr**.

Like:

```
$where = array('pos > ?' => $poss);
$this -> update(array('pos' => new Zend_Db_Expr('pos - 1')), $where);
```